# Sympy with Cython produces singular matrix when attempting to find roots

Tags: python, cython, sympy

I am trying to solve a set of nonlinear equations using Sympy. This is my code with a few numbers changed and only one input value (the real code runs through 170,000 lines of data):

```
import sympy as sp

K0 = 2.00*10**-4
x2, y2 = sp.symbols('x2, y2')
x0 = 500
y0 = 500
R1 = ((x2 - x0)**2 + (y2 - y0)**2)**0.5
R2 = K0 * R1
H2 = sp.atan(R2 * (x2 - x0)/R1)
V2 = sp.atan(R2 * (y2 - y0)/R1)
x, y = sp.symbols('x, y')
x0 = 1.0
y0 = 2.0
x = R1 * H2
y = R1 * V2
dat = sp.nsolve([x - x0, y - y0], [x2, y2], [512, 512]) # This line is the problem
print "dat = %f, %f" % (dat[0], dat[1])
```

Purely with Python, the code runs fine and produces a good output - but it's very slow. To speed up the process, I used Cython to compile a .pyx file with the exact same code (in a definition, `def test()`), yet during run-time I'm met with:

```
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    demo.test()
  File "demo.pyx", line 17, in demo.test
    dat = sp.nsolve([x - x0, y - y0], [x2, y2], [512, 512])
  File "C:\...\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py", line 91, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2847, in nsolve
    x = findroot(f, x0, J=J, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 960, in findroot
    for x, error in iterations:
  File "C:\...\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 658, in __iter__
    s = self.ctx.lu_solve(Jx, fxn)
  File "C:\...\site-packages\mpmath\matrices\linalg.py", line 227, in lu_solve
    A, p = ctx.LU_decomp(A)
  File "C:\...\site-packages\mpmath\matrices\linalg.py", line 137, in LU_decomp
    raise ZeroDivisionError('matrix is numerically singular')
ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular
```

I have narrowed down the problem to the `x - x0` and `y - y0` part. For some reason, the compiled code cannot handle finding the roots when they're not equal to 0. Can nsolve simply not be converted to C using Cython? Is there something I'm missing that I have to do with Cython?

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit you'd get from using Cython here, if you could. `nsolve` doesn't do anything to solve the system, it only passes it to `mpmath.findroot` where the real work is done.  Also, the code looks like it could use a SciPy solver instead, with minimal changes.

Comment: @if.... I am trying to do something like what is done [here](https://studywolf.wordpress.com/2017/04/23/quick-calculations-with-sympy-and-cython/), where Cython is used to improve Sympy computation speed. Reading it again, however, I think he may be compiling the sympy functions themselves? I have not used Cython before, so I'm a little confused about what it does exactly. I will see if SciPy will work for this.

Comment: Your link uses a `sympy` tool (`autowrap`), http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/autowrap.html.  That's not the same as compiling your own code as `pyx`.

Comment: @hpaulj Ok, that makes sense. That method will be too complicated for what I'm trying to do I think. I figured it out with SciPy and it works very well. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sympy.lambdify` together with e.g. SciPy's solvers. If that is not fast enough you could use `symengine.Lambdify`.

Getting the function signatures right, and deriving the Jacobian, requires you to jump through hoops. If you want to use a library for that I have written [pyneqsys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyneqsys):

```
>>> from pyneqsys.symbolic import SymbolicSys
>>> neqsys = SymbolicSys([x2, y2], [x - x0, y - y0])
>>> neqsys.solve([512, 512])
Out[4]: 
(array([ 547.28609349,  594.58064617]),
     fjac: array([[ 0.91320338,  0.4075041 ],
       [-0.4075041 ,  0.91320338]])
     fun: array([ -1.37667655e-13,   1.52011737e-12])
 message: 'The solution converged.'
    nfev: 17
    njev: 2
     qtf: array([  1.55620322e-10,   4.63225371e-10])
       r: array([ 0.02751454,  0.023682  ,  0.03261983])
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([ 547.28609349,  594.58064617]))
```

If those 170 000 solves involves gradually changing parameters `pyneqsys` can exploit that (by propagating the solution as guess between solves). It can also use `symengine.Lambdify` automatically by setting the environment variable `SYM_BACKEND=sympysymengine`